# can not add panel to scrollPane, application has no change

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, preferredsize

I add `panel4` to scrollPane, but my application wasn't change. This is my code:

```
   public class Bill extends JPanel {
      //some Jlabels, JComboBox......
      public Bill(){

      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
      panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,1,10,20));
      //add some labels to panel

      JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
      panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,4,10,10 ));

        //add some components to panel

      JPanel panel3=new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1,10,10));
      panel3.add(CRTA);
      panel3.add(UKUPNO);
      panel3.add(jbtView);
      panel3.add(jbtCancel);
```

and finally panel4

```
     JPanel panel4=new JPanel();
     panel4.add(panel1, BorderLayout.WEST);
     panel4.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

     JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
     scrollPane.getViewport().add( panel4 );  
     add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
     add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

---

this is what I got

[image]

inside rectange is panel4( panel with numbers and comboboxes )

and this is when I change size
[image]

**No scroll shows**

Comment: before `add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);` add this line `setLayout(new BorderLayout());` and for panel4 set the layout as BorderLayout too..

Comment: I did  `add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);` and its working...thank you!!!

Comment: Hm...should I post it as and answer?

Comment: @brano88: yes you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you should add everything on panel4 (including panel3) and then add panel4 on `JScrollPane`. After that, add that `JScrollPane` on `CENTER` of `JTabbedPane`.

Also never call `setXXXSize` methods on your `JButton`'s.

**EDIT**

I played a bit with your idea:

[image]

I hope this will help you about look of your UI. And again: Don't call `setXXXSize` methods, let some other things to determine size of your component, like size of font in case of that `JTextField` right to "Total" `JLabel` or size of icons in these `JButton`'s in "Hot drinks" panel.

Comment: I didn't add `panel3` to `panel4` because I want to see all buttons on panel3. This method I use for size for some JButtons  `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 100));`

Answer (score 2):

```
JPanel panel4=new JPanel();
panel4.add(panel1, BorderLayout.WEST);
panel4.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout which always respects a components preferred size. The constraints that you attempt to specify are just ignored.

You can try:

```
JPanel panel4=new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
```

Comment: Did you look at all your panels to make sure they are using the layout manager you think they are?